# Link error (symbol from plugin)*

Tags: c++, arduino, linker

Its been a while since ive coded in c++/c and im a little confused as to what im doing wrong

I have three files, 2 .h and one .cpp.

The files are as follow

Base Menu

```
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define OLED_RESET 4
#define SSD1306_LCDHEIGHT 64
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_RESET);

class BaseMenu {
public:
    // for moving the menu up and down
    void moveDownMenu();
    void moveUpMenu();
    void selectMenu();

    // for changing the text and the positions
    void incrementText();
    void decrementText();

protected:
    //
    char menuTitlePos1[20];
    char menuTitlePos2[20];
    char menuTitlePos3[20];

    bool is_menuPos1_selected = true;
    bool is_menuPos2_selected = false;
    bool is_menuPos3_selected = false;

private:
    virtual void AbstractClass() = 0;
};
```

MainMenu.h

```
#include "BaseMenu.h"
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE 4

class MainMenu : BaseMenu {
private:

    // Constructor
    MainMenu() {};

public:
    static void init();
};
```

MainMenu.cpp

```
#include "MainMenu.h"

void MainMenu::init() {
    // clearing display
    display.clearDisplay();
    display.display();

    display.setTextSize(1);
    display.setTextColor(WHITE);
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            display.setTextSize(1);
            display.setTextColor(BLACK, WHITE);
            //display.println(MainMenuTitles[i]);
         }
        else {
            display.setTextSize(1);
            display.setTextColor(WHITE);
            //display.println(MainMenuTitles[i]);
        }
    }

    display.display();
}
```

When ever i go to build the code i get the following error.

```
MainMenu.cpp.o (symbol from plugin)*: In function display
(.text+0x0)*: multiple definition of display
TestingLibrary.cpp.o (symbol from plugin)*: (.text+0x0): first defined here

collect2.exe*: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can someone please shed some light as to what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What you are doing wrong is defining `display` in the header file, so by including it from two translation units, the object gets defined in both translation units. A duplicate definition. That's what the compiler is also telling you.